# MalformedJsonException only thrown during unit tests on Android Emulator

Tags: android, parsing, gson, mosh

I have a test suite that open JSON files. The tests do not pass on emulator <= API 23 and work fine on newer API Level.

There are two different kinds of exceptions:

`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at line 1 column 1025 $.ajsonelement`

and

`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1025 path $.ajsonelement`.

The weird thing is that those files work fine when I run the app and open them manually in the simulator.

I'm using gson but the problem also appears with Moshi.

Comment: do you use proper `gitIgnore` ? some times it happens due cached intermediates !!

Comment: probably the JSON  files on that emulator are corrupted? Have you checked the actual file on the emulator?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thanks! Your comment lead me to the root of the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. The json files were in `moduleName/src/test/resources/configs/`. I moved them to `moduleName/src/test/assets/configs/`

The code to load them was:

```
val assetConfig = InstrumentationRegistry 
            .getInstrumentation() 
            .context 
            .assets 
            .open(configFileName) 
val scanner = Scanner(assetConfig) 
return scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next() Charsets.UTF_8))
```

I replaced it with a Guava helper:

```
val assetConfig = InstrumentationRegistry
            .getInstrumentation()
            .context
            .assets
            .open(configFileName)
return CharStreams.toString(InputStreamReader(assetConfig, Charsets.UTF_8))
```

Everything loads fine for all emulator between API 18 and 26.